# Why is my donut not smooth and sculpting it causes distortion?

Tags: modeling, sculpting

Im completely new to blender and ive been following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6OTX3ZdYvEA&list=PLjEaoINr3zgEq0u2MzVgAaHEBt--xLB6U&t=0s

I started noticing around part 4, that my icing looks edgy and jagged especially when zooming in. At part 5 it got even worse when i started sculpting and those lines appeared.

[image]

Have i missed something or is it related to blender settings or gpu/cpu?

Comment: did you give it a Subdivision Surface modifier?

Comment: Check your dyntopo settings, this often catches me out, sometimes it manages to disable itself if you switch between views and then sculpting starts doing unexpected stuff

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Yes but i seem to have missed increasing the viewport, that did smooth it out (only in object mode thought) but it also gave more "distortion" ^^ Where do if find the dyntopo setting? Is the tutorial using this or multires?

Answer (score 1):

I think i figured it out. I made a copy of everything and did not hide it from the view which caused the distortion